# Editar el id de base de datos en PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de hacer que una consulta a la base de datos sea mas rápida la edición, me explico: Tengo el siguiente código "`SELECT * from bdd where id=17`"
Yo lo que quiero es al `ID` introducirlo desde un formulario, ya que todas las semanas manualmente tengo que actualizarlo.
Son muchos datos que tengo que actualizar a la misma vez, por ejemplo:

```
$sqlp = "SELECT * from bdd where id=17";
$resultp = mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlp);
$rowsp = mysqli_fetch_array($resultp);
if($rowsp){
echo '<th><img height="40px" src="/escudos/<?php  echo $rowsp['escudo']; ?>.png"></th>';
}

$sqlp = "SELECT * from bdd where id=7";
$resultp = mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlp);
$rowsp = mysqli_fetch_array($resultp);
if($rowsp){
echo '<th><img height="40px" src="/escudos/<?php  echo $rowsp['escudo']; ?>.png"></th>';
}
```

Como ven son dos imágenes, cada uno hace referencia a un `ID` distinto. Como dije lo que intento es al `"id"` introducirlo desde un formulario:

```
<form action="sids.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="id1" name="id1" placeholders="ID 1"/>
 <input type="text" id="id2" name="id2" placeholders="ID 2"/>

 <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Sigo sin poder resolver esto.

Comment: Es decir: **¿en tu formulario solo ingresar un `id` el cual se usará en tu consulta SQL y te filtre la información por ese mismo no?**

Comment: Claro. Exactamente eso. Ya la base de datos está armada, pero lo que me confunde es que tengo que actualizar 2 ids al mismo tiempo, pero que a la vez van a ser distintos

Comment: No comprendo lo que quieres, lo que deseas es ingresar dos ID por formulario, y luego esos dos ID  obtener su respectiva información o cambiar los ID  por otros id?. Seria bueno que re formules tu pregunta.

Comment: Ese planteamiento es un suicidio. Haz de cuenta que lo que quieres hacer es aprender a usar una pistola, y lo que estas haciendo no es darte un tiro en el pie, sino en la cabeza. Mejor lee esto y replantea tu lógica: https://inmensia.com/blog/20070223/elegir_clave_primaria_tabla_base_datos_oracle.html

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Lo que haces ahí es que consulte la información dependiendo del id, pero quieres que el id se mande por formulario?

Comment: Que el usuario ingrese un id de base de datos es pésima practica de programación, tendrás muchos problemas si lo haces.

Comment: Que recomiendan, porque si no, cada vez que quiero cambiar el equipo que juega tengo que entrar al sublime text y cambiar el id desde ahi

Comment: Cuántos registros se manejan ahí en esa tabla?

Comment: @MatiPHP creo que lo mejor es definir bien el modelo de datos, es decir si quieres manejar partidos por ejemplo puedes definir `equipos ` ,`jugadores`,`partidos`, los equipos pueden tener `juagdores dentros y escudos`... no se entiende muy bien lo que quieres hacer pero creeria que uan tabla intermedia te podria resolver

Comment: @DaxTter77 Solo hay 24, con equipo y escudo.  
IgmerRodriguez Como seria eso, algun ejemplo para tener como base?

Comment: Pero lo que quieres es hacerle un update a dos de esos registros, sino te entiendo mal, ¿cierto @MatiPHP?

Comment: En vez de introducir los IDs que es una pesima opción planteate tener 2 combos con los valores.

Answer (score 2):

En la pagina Oficial de PHP dan info para "bind" no se si realmente es lo que buscas hacer con tus "id":
[PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

```
/* Preparar una sentencia INSERT */
$consulta = "INSERT INTO myCity (Name, CountryCode, District) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$sentencia = $mysqli->prepare($consulta);

$sentencia->bind_param("sss", $val1, $val2, $val3);

$val1 = 'Stuttgart';
$val2 = 'DEU';
$val3 = 'Baden-Wuerttemberg';

/* Ejecutar la sentencia */
$sentencia->execute();
```

Comment: en el código del OP no se muestra ni la implementación de MVC ni tampoco que use sentencias preparadas, eso sin contar que el usa mysqli y no PDO

Comment: Cierto Aprendiz, usa mysqli de todas maneras tampoco esta muy clara la pregunta...si pudiera concretar un poco mas se podría dar una mejor respuesta, de todas maneras no entiendo porque no puedes utilizar el "bind" para esto...(edito codigo)

Answer (score 1):

para hacerlo debes de concatenar una variable donde recibas el id:

```
$id="17";//El valor de id lo recibes por los metodos: get,post,request en su caso como vayas a utilizarlo
$sqlp = "SELECT * from bdd where id=".$id.";";
$resultp = mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlp);
$rowsp = mysqli_fetch_array($resultp);
if($rowsp){
echo '<th><img height="40px" src="/escudos/<?php  echo $rowsp['escudo']; ?>.png"></th>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

propongo una solución mas simple por que no eliminas primero el registro y luego lo creas con el id correcto.

```
<?php
$eliminar = "delete from bdd where id=17"
$ingresar= "INSERT INTO myCity (Name, CountryCode, District) VALUES (?,?,?)"
$resuDel = mysqli_query($conexion,$eliminar);
if($resuDel){
    $resuIns = mysqli_query($conexion,$ingresar);
if($resuIns ){
  echo '<th><img height="40px" src="/escudos/"'.$rowsp['escudo'].'".png"></th>'
}
}
?>
```